# How to use a custom path for GitHub Actions workflow file?

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible to use GitHub Actions with a path other than `/.github/workflows/action.yml`?
For example, can I use `/foo/bar/.github/workflows/action.yml`?
(without `/.github/...` in root path)
If so, how can I achieve this?

I tried creating `/foo/bar/.github/workflows/action.yml` but it didn't work.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could let me know that this is impossible, even if it is mentioned somewhere in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the excerpt from the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions):

> You must store workflow files in the .github/workflows directory of your repository.

This means that you can have subfolders under `.github/workflows`, which contain more workflows/actions, but the root of the path must be `.github/workflows`.